# AWS Signature, Encoding, Verification

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, encoding, rsa, key-management

I have an POCO that I am generating signature for using AWS KeyManagementService

```
var signResponse= await client.SignAsync(new Amazon.KeyManagementService.Model.SignRequest()
        {
            KeyId = "keyid",
            MessageType = MessageType.RAW,
            SigningAlgorithm = SigningAlgorithmSpec.RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_256,
            Message = new System.IO.MemoryStream(JsonSerializer.Serialize(item).ToByteArray())
        });
```

I then convert sig `MemoryStream` to `string` and save in the database

`string sig = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(response.Signature.ToArray());`

Upon retrieval of the object (another request) I use verify signature

```
var verifyResponse = await client.VerifyAsync(new Amazon.KeyManagementService.Model.VerifyRequest()
        {
            KeyId = "keyid",
            MessageType = MessageType.RAW,
            SigningAlgorithm = SigningAlgorithmSpec.RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_256,
            Message = new System.IO.MemoryStream(JsonSerializer.Serialize(item).ToByteArray()),
            Signature = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sig ?? ""))
        });
```

and unfortunately it fails, as in signature isn't verified. If i put these two calls right one after the other and set the `Signature` of the `VerifyRequest` to `signReponse.Signature` verification is successful.

This leads me to believe it has something to do with encoding/decoding of the signature stream to store in in DB. I tried all the encodings available in `Encoding`.

Am I missing something conceptual? How should a signature be stored in this situation?

Comment: You seem to be interpreting the signature as a series of Unicode code points (using `Unicode.GetString(byte[])`). It's not. It's just binary data. Probably should be encoding it with `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])` instead.

Comment: Oh no I definitely get it's just binary. What I don't get is the general encoding concept so I got tangled. base64 just never occurred to me. That was it, thank you! Submit it as an answer, i'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be interpreting the signature as a series of Unicode code points (using `Unicode.GetString(byte[])`). It's not. It's just binary data. Probably should be encoding it with [`Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netcore-3.1) instead.